# Extended regex with Lookarounds Alternatives for grep but "conflicting matchers specified"

Tags: regex, grep

I can't feed my regex to `/bin/grep` resulting `conflicting matchers specified` error.

My regex I've tried:

```
rDURATION="(?<=duration:\').*?(?=\',)"
rFILE="(?<=file:\').*?(?=\',)"
rTITLE="(?<=title:\').*?(?=\',)"

/bin/grep -oPE "$rDURATION|$rFILE|$rTITLE|,"
```

or more complicated:

```
/bin/grep -oPE "(?<=duration:\').*?(?=\',)|(?<=file:\').*?(?=\',)|(?<=title:\').*?(?=\',)|,"
```

which I successfully passed here: https://regex101.com/r/FYYrt6/2

My test strings look like this one:

```
window.pl = [];window.pl.push({duration:'1:08:32',file:'https://stat3.deti-online.com/a/m4ado387zB2v21YhWLdEaQ/1570741200/files/skazki/skazki-andersena/snezhnaja-koroleva-1.mp3',title:'Снежная королева', group: ''});window.pl.push({duration:'1:24:31',file:'https://stat3.deti-online.com/a/5QMsqcSHRweEC5pYiMhPoQ/1570741200/files/skazki/skazki-andersena/snezhnaja-koroleva-2.mp3',title:'Снежная королева (второй вариант)', group: ''});
```

**UPD**

I expect **multiline output** with **3 substrings** and commas like this one:

```
1:08:32,https://stat3.deti-online.com/a/m4ado...mp3,Снежная королева,
```

I beleve that I just can't overcome `man grep`.. Need hivemind's help

Comment: I expect behaveour like this: $ echo 123qweASD | /bin/grep -oE "[0-9]+|[a-z]+" -->>
123
qwe

Comment: So you want something like `$ echo 123qweASD | grep -oE "[0-9]+|[a-z]+" | tr '\n' ' '` ?

Comment: Will you consider `awk` solution?

Comment: @unbearablelightness, no. Look grep exaple in my 1st commebt - it returns multiple lines

Comment: @anubhava , yes `awk` is acceptable, but.. it is `grep` in title

Comment: @viktorkho do you want the result on multiple lines or on one line?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness, multiline is preferable couse this `grep` is a part of pipeline

Comment: @UnbearableLightness , in question > I expect multiline output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider this `awk` solution:

```
awk -F "', *|[{}]|:' *" '{
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
   if ($(i-1) ~ /^(duration|file|title)$/) {
      printf("%s,", $i)
      if ($(i-1) == "title")
         print ""
   }
}' <<< "$str"
```

```
1:08:32,https://stat3.deti-online.com/a/m4ado387zB2v21YhWLdEaQ/1570741200/files/skazki/skazki-andersena/snezhnaja-koroleva-1.mp3,Снежная королева,
1:24:31,https://stat3.deti-online.com/a/5QMsqcSHRweEC5pYiMhPoQ/1570741200/files/skazki/skazki-andersena/snezhnaja-koroleva-2.mp3,Снежная королева (второй вариант),
```

Comment: Awesome `awk`'s field separator.. I'm impressed

Comment: ready to accept this answer as correct if there are no versions with `grep`

Comment: > "Awesome awk's field separator"
Lol, this guy is Author of the guide to regular expressions with Java